# Regex to match a list of alphanumeric ids of a JSON fragment inside HTML

Tags: node.js, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'm trying to compose a regular expression to match the following situation:

In a Node.js project I have a multiline string that contains a big HTML code mixed with some JS with this structure:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ... more code ...
      },
      "bookIds" : [
        "abc123",
        "qwe456",
        "asd789"
      ],
      ... more code, and in another json:
      },
      "bookIds" : [
        "foo111",
        "bar222",
        "baz333"
      ],
      ... more code ...
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My goal is to get the first list of bookIds:

```
abc123
qwe456
asd789
```

So, as you can see, the conditions that I'm working with, for now, are:

- Search the first `"bookIds" : [` appearance and stop at the next `]`

I got something like that with: `/bookIds" : \[([\S\s]*?)\]/`. Yeah, conceptually I though about finding the first string `bookIds`, start after the first `[` after that, and stop before the next `]`, but I don't know how to do it. I'm now getting documented about lookahead & lookbehinds.

- Now I need to search (or loop) inside that match and get what's inside quotes (I know how could I do that individually: `/"(.*?)"/`)

But unfortunately I've been hours googling and trying and I'm not getting it to work (neither in my Node project nor the tests I'm trying in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com))

Any suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: is this what you're trying to do https://regex101.com/r/CO8RS9/1/

Comment: @CodeManiac It is almost exactly, now I just need to ignore the quotes and commas, so I can get only the ids and iterate the result to perform an operation over every single id. Anyway, you just saved me a lot of time, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"bookIds"\s*:\s*\[([^\]]+?)]`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CO8RS9/1/)

```js
let str = `<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      "bookIds" : [
        "abc123",
        "qwe456",
        "asd789"
      ],
      "bookIds" : [
        "foo111",
        "bar222",
        "baz333"
      ],
    <\/script>
  <\/body>
<\/html>`

let op = str.match(/"bookIds"\s*:\s*\[([^\]]+?)]/m)
console.log(op[1].replace(/[\s"]+/g,''))
```

Comment: Thank you! you saved me a lot of time!